# A Delphi Custom Control: A TRichEdit with a TLabel Above It

Tags: delphi, controls

I want to create an custom control (descendant of TRichEdit).
I simply want add some text above the editfield.

I've created my own control and I override the constructor to create a TLabel for the caption.
It works, but my problem: How is it possible to move the label above the richedit?
When I set Top := -5 the label begins to disappaer.

Here's the code of the constructor:

```
constructor TDBRichEditExt.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  lblCaption := TLabel.Create(self);
  lblCaption.Parent := parent;
  lblCaption.Caption := 'Header';
  lblCaption.Top := -5;
end;
```

I think it's logic that the label disappaers since the richedit is the parent. 
I've tried

```
lblCaption.Parent := self.parent;
```

To make the form which owns the richedit the parent - but this dosn't work...

How could I achieve this?
Thank you all!

Comment: Have you looked at the [`TLabeledEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ExtCtrls.TLabeledEdit) control in the *ExtCtrls* unit? It should show you *exactly* how to do what you're after.

Comment: Rob Kennedy is right. TLabeledEdit is a TEdit with a TLabel above it. It is the standard example of this procedure. Read the source code and learn. If you want some more explanations, read my answer below instead (in addition).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I think it's logic that the label
>   disappaers since the richedit is the
>   parent

This is wrong. In your code, the parent of the `TLabel` is the parent of the `TDBRichEditExt`, as it should be. Notice that, in a method of `TDBRichEditExt`, `Parent` and `Self.Parent` is the same thing. *If* you would like the parent of the `TLabel` to be the `TDBRichEditExt` itself - which you do *not* - then you should set  `lblCaption.Parent := self;`.

Now, if the parent of the `TLabel` is the parent of the `TDBRichEditExt`, then the `Top` property of the `TLabel` refers to the parent of `TDBRichEditExt`, not to the `TDBRichEditExt` itself. Hence, if the parent of the `TDBRichEditExt` is a `TForm`, then `Top := -5` means that the `TLabel` will be positioned five pixels *above* the form's upper edge. You mean

```
lblCaption.Top := Self.Top - 5;
```

But -5 is a far too small number. What you really should use is

```
lblCaption.Top := Self.Top - lblCaption.Height - 5;
```

which in addition makes a 5 px space between the label and the Rich Edit.

Also, you would like

```
lblCaption.Left := Self.Left;
```

**Another issue**

But this will not work, because at the time the component is created, I do not think that the Parent has been set yet. So what you will need is to do the positioning of the label at a more appropriate time. In addition, this will move the label each time your component is moved, which is very important!

```
TDBRichEditExt = class(TRichEdit)
private
  FLabel: TLabel;
  FLabelCaption: string;
  procedure SetLabelCaption(LabelCaption: string);
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  procedure SetBounds(ALeft: Integer; ATop: Integer; AWidth: Integer; AHeight: Integer); override;
published
  LabelCaption: string read FLabelCaption write SetLabelCaption;
end;

procedure TDBRichEditExt.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  if not assigned(Parent) then
    Exit;
  FLabel.Parent := self.Parent;
  FLabel.Top := self.Top - FLabel.Height - 5;
  FLabel.Left := self.Left;
end;
```

**Details**

In addition, when you hide the `TDBRichEditExt`, you want to hide the label as well. Thus you need

```
protected
  procedure CMVisiblechanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_VISIBLECHANGED;
```

where

```
procedure TDBRichEditExt.CMVisiblechanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if assigned(FLabel) then
    FLabel.Visible := Visible;
end;
```

And similarly for the `Enabled` property, and you also need to update the parent of the `TLabel` each time the parent of the `TDBRichEditExt` is changed:

```
protected
  procedure SetParent(AParent: TWinControl); override;
```

with

```
procedure TDBRichEditExt.SetParent(AParent: TWinControl);
begin
  inherited;
  if not assigned(FLabel) then Exit;
  FLabel.Parent := AParent;
end;
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much for this detailed information and your effort to explain it!

Comment: There are more to it than Andreas has explained (very well, must be said +1 for it), see TLabeledEdit source in ExtCtrls.pas. For example, form notification handling.